# Unable to get required result using preconnect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, amazon-s3, tcp

My site is trying to download images from s3.amazonaws.com around 5 images like `https://s3.amazonaws.com/path**********.png`. I tried adding the below tags inside the head tag for pre-connection to the s3.amazonaws.com site so that there can be some milliseconds saving.

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com"\>

<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com"\>
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please help here?

I was expecting an early connection to the s3.amazonaws.com so that whenever the images are required they can download directly instead of waiting for a connection which could save a few milliseconds to one second time.

Note: I am using preconnect only for this s3 amazon only and chrome latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefetch or preload command too. In order to load data from specific url.

moreover you can also use javascript to load the object on webpage.

```js
// Create a new element with the preconnect URL in
var l = document.createElement('link');
l.rel = 'preconnect';
l.href = "[scheme]://[hostname]"; // Replace this with the service to preconnect to
document.head.appendChild(l); // Browser will now establish a connection
```

Usage Example

```js
function setupPreConnect(){
    // We wrap in a conditional so we're not spamming the DOM with every keypress
    if (!window.ecosiapreconnected){

        // The user has started typing in the text box, so take that as a sign we're going to be going to Ecosia.
        // Tell the browser to pre-connect to speed up the response
        var l = document.createElement('link');
        l.rel = 'preconnect';
        l.href = "S3 url";//use S3 URl
        document.head.appendChild(l);

        // Set a variable so we don't inject a new element if they press another key 
        window.ecosiapreconnected = 1;
    }
}

// Trigger the preconnect once a user starts typing in the search box
document.getElementById('searchbox').addEventListener('keypress',setupPreConnect);

// If you'd prefer, you could do it when the searchbox is brought into focus
// document.getElementById('searchbox').addEventListener('focus',setupPreConnect);
```

Use below url's for the preload and prefetch refs:
https://nitropack.io/blog/post/resource-hints-performance-optimization.

https://snippets.bentasker.co.uk/page-1908140902-Make-the-browser-preconnect-to-a-domain-via-javascript-Javascript.html